# Looping over multiple variables in R

Tags: r, loops

I have been using Stata and the loops are easily executed there. However, in R I have faced some errors in looping over variables. I tried some of the codes over here and it does not work. Basically, I am trying to clean the data by logging the values. I had to convert negative values to positive first before logging them.

I intend to loop over multiple firm statistics on the dataframe but I faced errors in doing so.

```
varlist <- c("revenue", "profit", "cost")`

for (v in varlist) {
  data$log_v <- log(abs(ifelse(data$v>1, data$v, NA)))
  data$log_v <- ifelse(data$v<0, data$log_v*-1,data$log_v)
}
```

> Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*,"log_v", value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 9

Comment: can you please make your question reproducible by including a sample of your data? You can do this with `dput(head(data, 20))` and including the output in your question

Comment: Will take note of this in the future :) Thanks!

Comment: (i) I was quite puzzled at first, because usually "logging" means "making a log entry of something", while "logarithmizing" means "calculating the log() of something" :-)

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity: how do you justify your procedure, that is, taking the absolute value to logarithmize it? Negative revenue will now have the same value as positive revenue.

Comment: Hi @January, apologies I usually used the term logging loosely in the office as taking the logarithm of a term. On the negative revenue point, I first take the absolute of the revenue and multiply by -1 for those firms with negative revenue :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be assuming that data$log_v is getting read as data$log_profit, but R's going to take it own it's own and read it as "log_v" all 3 times.  This example might not be quite everything you're trying to do but it might help you. It's taking a list of variables and referencing them via their string names.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(15), y = rnorm(15))

vars <- c("x", "y")

for (v in vars) {
  df[paste0("log_", v)] <- log(abs(df[v]))
}
```

Here's roughly the same thing in data.table.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(15), y = rnorm(15))
dt[, `:=`(log_x = log(abs(x)), log_y = log(abs(y)))]
```

Comment: Yes. I am assuming that data$log_v is getting read as data$log_profit. Apologies as I am new to R language. Will try your method now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation to the source of your confusion:

A `data.frame` is a special type of list, it's elements are vectors of the same length – columns. Normally, you access an element of a list using the `[[` function, for example `df[["revenue"]]`. Instead of `"revenue"`, you can also use a variable, such as `df[[varlist[1]]]`. So far, so good.

However, lists have a *convenience* operator, `$`, which allows you to access the elements with less typing: `df$revenue`. Unfortunately, you cannot use variables this way: this by design. Since you don't have to use quotes with `$`, the operator cannot know whether you mean `revenue` as the literal name of the element or `revenue` as the variable that holds the literal name of the element.

Therefore, if you want to use variables, you need to use the `[[` function, and not the `$`. Since programmers hate typing and want to make code as terse as possible, various ways around it have been invented, such as `data.tables` and `tidyverse` (I am exaggerating a bit here).

Also, here is a tidyverse solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
varlist <- c("revenue", "profit", "cost") 
df <- data.frame(revenue=rnorm(100), profit=rnorm(100), cost=rnorm(100))

df <- df %>% mutate_at(varlist, list(log10 = ~ log10(abs(.))))
```

*Explanation*:

- `mutate_all` applies `log10(abs(.))` to every column. The dot `.` is a temporary variable that hold the column values for each of the columns.
- by default, `mutate_all` will replace the existing variables. However, if instead of providing a function (`~ log10(abs(.))`) you provide a named list (`list(log10 = ~ log10(abs(.)))`), it will add new columns using `log10` as a suffix in column name.
- this method makes it easy to apply several functions to your columns, not only the one.

See? No (obvious) loops at all!